# group.com.apple.notes is taking up huge amounts of disk space

Tags: macos, notes.app, disk-space

Further to [yesterdays question about Apple Notes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390836/free-up-space-used-by-notes) taking up huge amounts of space on my iPhone, on my Mac the folder `group.com.apple.notes\media` is taking up 13.1GB.

[image: Folder list with disk space]

Each folder has a zip file and the contents of the file. Often the folder is duplicated with a different GUID. The folder contains some of my images and movies, but I can't find any corresponding notes with these images.

What they are from, and can I delete the contents of the folder to resolve my Apple Notes woes?